# Why don't my conditions for a rock paper scissors game work?

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements

So here is how i stored the variables for the computer's choice and the player's choice for a rock paper scissors game:[bot and user choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNNFl.png) and here is how the site look like: [the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wgn5L.png). So, my intention for this was to make it so that the function would considers those conditions and alert the out come (Ex: "you win" or "you lose"). However, it ignores both of those first 2 conditions and go straight to the last "else" which alert that the game tied even if the "oo" which is the computer's choice is for example rock and your choice is paper. Now, i honestly do not know how to fix this since it detect no errors with my conditions and does not says if the variable is stored wrong, so please help me with this, and also all the part above the part when the computer choice, "oo", and the user choice are stored was not made by me, i'm using this work (https://codepen.io/Re3ker/pen/VYBXBj) to improve my format (just for personal project)

Here is the code for the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var users = [],
    shuffled = [],
    loadout = $("#loadout"),
    insert_times = 30,
    duration_time = 10000;
  $("#roll").click(function(){
    users = [];


    var lines = $('textarea').val().split('\n');
    if(lines.length < 2){
      $("#msgbox").slideToggle(100);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#msgbox").slideToggle(100);
      }, 3000);
      return false;
    }  
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
      if(lines[i].length > 0){
        users.push(lines[i]);
      }
    }
    $("#roll").attr("disabled",true);
    var scrollsize = 0,
    diff = 0;
    $(loadout).html("");
    $("#log").html("");
    loadout.css("left","100%");
    if(users.length < 10){
      insert_times = 20;
      duration_time = 5000;
    }else{
      insert_times = 10;
      duration_time = 10000;
    }
    for(var times = 0; times < insert_times;times++){
      shuffled = users;
      shuffled.shuffle();
      for(var i = 0;i < users.length;i++){
        loadout.append('<td><div class="roller"><div>'+shuffled[i]+'</div></div></td>');
        scrollsize = scrollsize + 192;
      }
    }


    diff = Math.round(scrollsize /2);
    diff = randomEx(diff - 300,diff + 300);
    $( "#loadout" ).animate({
      left: "-="+diff
    },  duration_time, function() {
      $("#roll").attr("disabled",false);
      $('#loadout').children('td').each(function () {
        var center = window.innerWidth / 2;
        if($(this).offset().left < center && $(this).offset().left + 185 > center){
          var userChoice=document.querySelector('input[name="one"]:checked').value;
          var oo = $(this).children().text();
          var a="rock";
          var b="paper";
          var c="scissors";

          if(((userChoice=="paper")&&(oo==a))||((userChoice=="rock")&&(oo==c))|| ((userChoice=="scissors")&&(oo==b))){
            alert("You wins! ");
          }else if(((userChoice=="rock")&&(oo==b)) || ((userChoice=="paper")&&(oo==c))|| ((userChoice=="scissors")&&(oo==a))){
            alert("you lose! ");
          }else{
            alert("A tie, PLAY AGAIN");
          }
          $("#log").append("The computer chose \n"+oo);
        }
      });
    });
  });
  Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
    var counter = this.length, temp, index;
    while (counter > 0) {
      index = (Math.random() * counter--) | 0;
      temp = this[counter];
      this[counter] = this[index];
      this[index] = temp;
    }
  }
  function randomEx(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
  }
});
```

Comment: Better to post code than images.

Comment: Hi, i just did it but i just want to say sorry, i'm quite new to this site.

Comment: Console.log the `oo` variable. I guess that `$(this).children().text()` *may* be wrong.

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette, yeah i just did that but nothing seems to be wrong, it popped up in the console log just fine. However, it still ignores the 2 first conditions and go straight to the last "else".

Comment: Also console log `userChoice` then...

Comment: @ Louys Patrice Bessette, nvm i just fixed it, i tried to just cheated it without considering that "textarea" count the space between the words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, the condition and variable were stored right but i cheated using the textarea:

rock
                   paper
                   scissors

which it counted the space in from the start to the "rock","paper" and "scissors". So all i had to do was make it stick to the beginning without any space between